# Selecting Matching values from three different table and combining them in one table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have Four tables as follows

```
Review (REV_ID pk , REV_NAME)

Meeting (MEETING_ID pk,MEETING_NAME,REV_ID fk to Review)

Task (TASK_ID pk,TASK_NAME,REV_ID fk to Review)

Answer (ANS_ID pk,ANS_NAME,REV_ID fk to Review)
```

Now I want to select a particular Review and want to create a table with

Linked meetings

Linked answers

Linked tasks

How shall I proceed with it?

I tried writing join query but I was only able to get data if Rev_ID is present in all tables?

```
select * from 
(SELECT *
FROM meeting
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM review WHERE meeting.rev_id 
=review.rev_id)
and meeting.rev_id=142),
(SELECT *
FROM answer
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM review WHERE answer.rev_id 
=rev.rev_id)
and answer.ans_rev_id=142),

(SELECT *
FROM task
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM review WHERE task.rev_id 
=review.rev_id)
and task.rev_id=142) r;
```

Note : Here I tried static Rev_ID =142 to check data.

From above query i am getting output only if data exist in all four table, But if Data does not exist in any table, It does not return remaining value.

I want at-least names of all table's in final output.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, let us know if this meets your requirements.

```
  SELECT rv.rev_id,
       rv.rev_name,
       mt.meeting_name,
       tk.task_name,
       ans.ans_name
  FROM review rv
       LEFT OUTER JOIN meeting mt ON (rv.rev_id = mt.rev_id)
       LEFT OUTER JOIN task tk ON (rv.rev_id = tk.rev_id)
       LEFT OUTER JOIN answer ans ON (rv.rev_id = ans.rev_id)
 WHERE rv.rev_id = 142
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b42d9f/1)

If the above SQL is fine, prefix it with create table or view syntax to combine them into one.

Comment: Hi , No its still same, Only returning data if rv.rev_id matches in all tables, if record for rev_id is missing any table then its returning no data

Comment: @Ekaz I have updated the answer by adding `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

Comment: @Ekaz Please modify your question by adding expected output or results.

Comment: LEFT OUTER JOIN Solved the problem, Thanks you, Appreciate your help.

Comment: @Ekaz You are most welcome, glad to know the problem has been resolved.